# Is this a legitimate teratoma for a human pluripotent stem cell assay?

Tags: development, histology, stem-cells

I can't quite make out this teratoma:

[image]
                         [<sup>[Source: FIG 3B]</sup>](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3900981/figure/F3/)

I can kind of guess at ectoderm, mesoderm and endoderm structures based on generalized textbook developmental biology references but it looks like the stain was messed up. Shouldn't a hematoxylin-eosin stain be blue and red? Is this a legitimate confirmation of germ cell development from human pluripotent stem cells?